# Usage of 'airman' vs 'pilot' in 1939 England

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, british-english, military

Can a civilian in 1939 England use the general term 'airman' to describe a man who is undergoing pilot training but has not yet completed it. Or does the term 'airman' in the RAF always refer to auxiliary crew and the civilian would already be using 'pilot' to differentiate? Thanks for your advice!

Comment: history aside...in English a pilot is always an airman, but an airman is not always a pilot.

Comment: Agreed.  I went with airman to be on the safe side but am having second thoughts on whether he would have to be called 'pilot' as he's on his way to becoming one.

Comment: You need to give dictionary definitions from say Collins and CED. There appear to be different and conflicting senses in use even today.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that in some articles and personal accounts, people qualify their usage ahead of their texts (as in 'The term 'airman' is used as follows because...' In a novel, it's more difficult to differentiate.

Comment: If you look up dictionaries you'll find that airman can be a rank, or even part of the aircrew.

Comment: I think "aeronaut" probably beat out most other terms early on, though by 1939 I believe the term had narrowed down to a balloon pilot.

Comment: [This reference](https://books.google.com/books?id=9sSRUdgsxcEC&pg=PA163&dq=%22aeronaut%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5pePl1c7aAhVl94MKHeDXBkkQ6AEIWTAI#v=onepage&q=%22aeronaut%22&f=false) from 1930 suggests aeronaut, aviator, and pilot as terms for a non-military aircraft operator in the US.

Answer (score 1):

A civilian who was a typical member of the public might well have used the term 'airman' to mean any person who was a pilot or member of an aircraft's flying or ground crew, whether a member of the Royal Air Force or not. Later, when the war was well under way, and mass recruitment had taken place, and military terminology had become more widely known, such a person might be aware that the RAF called all personnel under the rank of sergeant "airmen". Women did not join the RAF; they belonged to a auxiliary organisation called the Women's Auxiliary Air Force (WAAF). A person undergoing flying training was called a 'student pilot' and was not correctly called simply a 'pilot' until he had passed final tests and examinations. At that point he received his flying brevet (Pilot's Wings).

Here is some background information:

https://www.rafmuseum.org.uk/research/online-exhibitions/taking-flight/pathway-to-pilot/second-world-war.aspx

Comment: 'Trainee' was also commonly used. My dad joined the RAF in '39 and learned to fly at the famous Gillies Flying School in Canada. He was later an instructor pilot there. For additional info on this subject, see Ted Barris's *[Behind the Glory](https://www.amazon.com/Behind-Glory-Canadas-Role-Allied/dp/0887627234)*

Comment: Thank you very much, Michael. That's what I'd hoped to narrow in on. I had come across that website also, which has a lot of other good info. 

Answer (score 0):

A civilian in 1939 England?Likely **pilot**

[image: ngram-BrE]